# Jquery tabs navigation dots to be positioned based on the height of the tabs

Tags: jquery, tabs

I hope you guys can help me with this.

The navigation, **tabmenunav** has 3 small dots at the bottom of the tabs, I need to calculate the height of each tab and position them at the bottom. at the moment are all in position absolute and doesn't look good.

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/QxgDr/24/

**Jquery**

```
(function tabszIndex() {

$('ul.tabmenu > li > a').each(function(e) {
    $("#tabmenunav").append("<a href='javascript:void(0);' class=''>&#8226;</a>");
});

$('ul.tabmenu > li > a').click(function(e) {
    var selectedTabIndex = $(this).parent().attr('id').substring(3); //parseInt(this.hash.substring(4));
    $('ul.tabmenu a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('#tabmenunav a').removeClass('active');
    $('#tabmenunav a').eq($(this).parent().index()).addClass('active');
    var i = 0;
    $('.tabmenu li').css('z-index', function(index) {
        var z = index < selectedTabIndex ? 1 : (index > selectedTabIndex ? --i : 0);
        return z
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
$('#tabmenunav a').click(function() {
    var idx = $(this).index();
    $('> a', $('ul.tabmenu > li').eq(idx)).trigger('click');

})
var lastTabIndex = $('.tab').length - 1;
$('.tab').each(function(i) {
    if (i != lastTabIndex) {
        $(this).append("<a href='javascript:void(0)' class='next-tab mover'>Next Tab &#187;</a>");
    }
    if (i != 0) {
        $(this).append("<a href='javascript:void(0)' class='prev-tab mover'>&#171; Prev Tab</a>");
    }
});
var tabMenu = $('.tab');
$('.next-tab, .prev-tab').click(function() {
    var newTabIndex = $(this).hasClass('next-tab') ? 1 : -1;
    var idx = (parseInt($(this).parents('li').attr('id').substring(3)) + newTabIndex);
    $('ul.tabmenu > li#tab' + idx + ' > a').trigger('click');
});
$('> a', $('ul.tabmenu > li').eq(0)).trigger('click');
```

})();

Comment: I edited my answer to include a suggestion for shifting your three small dots at the bottom, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the first things that came to mind was the use of `offset()`. [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/offset/#offset2). You can use that to both capture the location of an element and then turn around and use that to set the location of another element. I have used this technique to modify your [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/QxgDr/25/).

Here is what I added:

```
var offsetGoal = $("#Overview").offset();
$("#Features").offset({ top: offsetGoal.top, left: (offsetGoal.left+100) });
$("#Technical").offset({ top: offsetGoal.top, left: (offsetGoal.left+200) });
```

Perhaps that will work for you.

**Edit**: Oops, I just noticed that you were asking about shifting the three small dots. I came up with the following to adjust their position which you might find useful.

I decided to calculate the number of li elements that you have in your menu (assuming you eventually have more) and multiply that by a set number of pixels to adjust by.

```
// However many elements in our tab menu should reinforce how far down to shift the navigation elements.
var shiftDotsBy = $(".tabmenu>li").size() * 3;
// Find the current position and just shift it downward
var dotsCurrentPos = $("#tabmenunav").offset();
$("#tabmenunav").offset({top: (dotsCurrentPos.top+shiftDotsBy), left: dotsCurrentPos.left});
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/QxgDr/26/).

**Edit**: This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QxgDr/28/) has been updated and shifts the dots based on which tab has been clicked and their relative height difference. Here is the approach:

```
// tab index is one-based; assuming each tab is twenty pixels lower than the previous one
var shiftDotsBy = (selectedTabIndex - 1) * 20;
var dotsCurrentPos = $("#tabmenunav").offset();
// Based on the original position of the dots determined outside this event, shift the dots by how far each tab extends down
$("#tabmenunav").offset({top: (dotsOrigPos.top+shiftDotsBy), left: dotsCurrentPos.left});
```

Taking these ideas you should have lots of control over how you want your dots to appear and shift around.

Comment: thanks for your help, but I need the tabmenunav to be inside the tabs.

Comment: so is the tab3 has more content I want the tabmenunav to shift at the bottom.

Comment: @DD77, I'm still not completely clear what you're hoping to accomplish, but [this is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QxgDr/28/) where the dots shift around based on which tab has been clicked. You should be able to take these ideas and modify them to suit your preference.

Comment: @ veeTrain that's is almost perfect, thanks, why does afect also my #tab1<a>#tab2<a>#tab3<a> on the top? is that possible to fix it?

Comment: @DD77; you're welcome. I'm not sure what you mean by also affecting your `#tab1...`, etc. You want them to shift too? They stay put in my browsers. Be sure to vote up and accept this answer if you have found it useful. Thanks!

Comment: SUre I will. the a.Features, a.Overview, a.Technical they have some inline style, some left and top stuff on them. Is that possible to remove it?

Comment: @DD77- Is [this what you're after](http://jsfiddle.net/QxgDr/29/)? I just removed the left and top modification to those elements; I mistakenly assumed you wanted that. Sorry; glad I could help!